# How do I configure the OpenNLP Brat Annotation Service?

Tags: java, opennlp, brat

Hi I am trying to get OpenNLP's Brat Annotation Service working with the BRAT annotator.  I can get OpenNLP's Brat annotation Service started, with the following command:

```
bin/brat-annotation-service NameFinderAnnService -serverPort 8999 ~/myNameFinderModel.bin
```

The server responds with log messages about glassfish and grizzly bears staring on port 8999. Everything appears ok...

On the BRAT annotator side, I have a tools.conf file containing:

```
[options]
[normalization]
[search]
[annotators]
OpenNLP tool:openNLP, model:openNLP,  <URL>:http://localhost:8999/ner
[disambiguators]
```

When I try to use my model (Data > Automatic Annotators, openNLP) I get an unknown connection error.  Tagger Service OpenNLP returned the error "Errno 111] conection refused".  I know the url exists.  I can use firefox on the server where BRAT is running open the url http://localhost:8999/ .

****** Edit:  I had a typo in my tools.conf file.  I fixed the typo, and the error changed to

Tagger service OpenNLP returned the error: 404 Not Found

Am I leaving a step out?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the OpenNLP brat annotation service (v1.8.3).  The bug is fixed and will be available in v 1.8.4.  There was also a problem with my tools.conf file.  I have edited the question to show the appropriate format.  I hope it helps the next person trying to connect the BRAT annotator to the OpenNLP annotation service.

Comment: If you reuse to use the automatic annotator in brat, would you please have an eye on my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63558127/8844500) ? By the way, what is OpenNLP brat ? Is it different from [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org) ?